# Is the file recorded with android AudioRecorder class saved somewhere?

Tags: android, audio, directory, save, record

I'm studying this example now http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html and I'm curious is the file saved somewhere after recording it? Which part of this code saves it? How to set the saving directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that sets the file name:

```
public AudioRecordTest() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
}
```

You can see where mFileName is used in startRecording()

```
private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}
```

Comment: So the setOutputFile() method sets the directory where the file is saved, yes? And after saving it I can see the file with other apps or not?

Comment: In this case yes because you are writing to the external storage directory. There are other options for making it invisible to other apps, but it sounds like this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's what I want for now, but what about if I wanted not to save this file to the storage but send it to another device or upload it somewhere instead and not keep it in my phone's storage?

Comment: If you know specifically where and how to upload it, you can do it using the HTTP classes. In Android often times we allow the user to simply share by sending an intent. The Android system then lets the user choose between the different ways to handle it (if they had SoundCloud for example installed that would be on the list). Here's plenty of info: http://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html

Comment: Thank you, you helped me very much and gave some interesting ideas. But what if I want to send it directly to another device? Not uploading somewhere, but directly. Is that possible?

Comment: That's another question and I doubt the stackoverflow overlords want me to answer this here, but how do you plan on the two devices communicating? If you can count on NFC there's info at the link in my last comment. There are WiFi peer-to-peer APIs and also Bluetooth. But again, you could avoid writing a bunch of code for those APIs by using intents. When I share a file in ES File Explorer for example, included in the options "Bluetooth", "Send by LAN", and "WiFi Direct".

Comment: Well, I understand what you are suggesting, but I want to send the file from device to device which are far from each other, just like sending messages through viber or photos through snapchat.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with snapchat but I'm confident there is an intermediate web server being used. The stackoverflow UI is now complaining about an extended discussion so you should ask a new question.

Comment: I guess so too. Maybe I should use ftp or something like that. Okay thank you. I'll see what I can do.